# How to handle SSIS solution with an excel source having multiple headers

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, header, unpivot

I am working on a package that requires I import an excel sheet with multiple headers. I am suppose to unpivot the top column (top header) and make that a row and also unpivot some columns in the actual bottom columns.

I have created the package using just the actual bottom columns. I then hard coded the top column into the table using derived column.

Here's an example of what I am looking for

Sample Raw Data and Target Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to un-pivot or reverse-pivot the input. In SSIS you can use the unpivot transformation,

Shared a good walkthrough below, hope this helps.

https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-ssis-pivot-and-ssis-unpivot-transformation/

KR,
Alex